# What am I missing!? Simple symbolic sum not simplifying

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm VERY confused: in what universe is the following not zero?

```
FullSimplify[2*Sum[Subscript[f, i], {i, 1, q}] - Sum[2*Subscript[f, i], {i, 1, q}]]
```

Mathematica gives:

[image]

Comment: `Factor[Sum[2*Subscript[f, m], {m, 1, q}]]` does not factor either.

Comment: I believe that Mathematica does not do what you assume is "the mathematically mature thing" with "abstract" vectors or "abstract" sums, i.e. where the length of the vector or the bounds on the sum are symbols instead of specific concrete integer constants.

Comment: I guess not. On the other hand it is perfectly capable of dealing with the above if you replace f_i with, say Sin[i].

Answer (score 1):

`FullSimplify` and `Simplify` do simplification by applying a series of rules.  Evidently, there is no rule for handling this case.  If one is created by

```
t2[e_] := With[{ans = e /. Sum[Times[i_Integer , a___], b___] -> {i, a, b}}, 
   ans[[1]] Sum[Evaluate[ans[[2]]], Evaluate[ans[[3]]]]]
```

Then the desired simplification occurs.

```
FullSimplify[2*Sum[Subscript[f, m], {m, 1, q}] - Sum[2*Subscript[f, m], {m, 1, q}], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t2}]
(* 0 *)
```

**Update (Thanks to Kuba)**

Simplier is

```
t2[e_] := e /. Sum[Times[i_Integer , a___], b___] :> i Sum[a, b]
```

Comment: +1, nice. But I really think M should have done it without all this coding. Maple have no problem giving zero. screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ejEHu.png)

Comment: @Nasser My solution is, of course, quite rudimentary.  The general solution would be to factor the summand and move each factor that is independent of the index outside the `Sum`.  I agree that Mathematica's list of `TransformationFunctions` should include such a rule.