# Applying the common factor to each term of a series

Tags: series-expansion

I have a series like this:

```
Sum[(n/z)^(1 - j + n)*Binomial[1 + n, j]*G[j], {j, 0, 1 + n}]/ ((1 + n)*(n/z)^n)
```

[image: Before]

where `G[j]` is, at this stage, "some function", unspecified. `n` is usually pretty large and at some point I'll be truncating the series with an `O(n+2)` term at the end; but let's not go there just yet.

What I would like to see is, as you might expect:

[image: After]

or

```
Sum[((n/z)^(1 - j)*Binomial[1 + n, j]*G[j])/(1 + n), {j, 0, 1 + n}]
```

I can't see any way from getting from one to the other and get rid of the notion that simple rearrangements of terms are something that I ought to be able to do.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Somewhat related: [21007](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21007/how-to-simplify-a-complicated-sum-in-terms-of-power-sums), [73548](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73548/what-am-i-missing-simple-symbolic-sum-not-simplifying), [82596](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82596/how-to-simplify-exponents-of-the-form-exp-lefti-frac2-pinn1-right-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exp = Sum[(n/z)^(1 - j + n)*Binomial[1 + n, j]*G[j], {j, 0, 1 + n}]/((1 + n)*(n/z)^n); 

exp /. a_ Sum[x_, y___] :> Sum[a x, y]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1.  Or perhaps `exp /. a_ Sum[x_, y___] /; FreeQ[a, Alternatives @@ {y}[[All, 1]]] :> Sum[a x, y]` for the cautious.  (Or ``! Internal`DependsOnQ[..]`` instead of `FreeQ`, but that might allow more than is desired; e.g. nested sums with the same index.  While legal in *M*, no editor would probably allow it.)

Comment: Thank you @MichaelE2, for the vote and the caution. Didn't think about nested sums and possible dependence of `a` on indices.